# ExtJS 5 bind combobox to selection

Tags: javascript, extjs, data-binding

Let's imagine a simple application : User Management. In the main view we have a list of users in a grid; selecting a user will enable the 'Edit' button.
We are grabbing the selected row in the grid (using the `bind {selection : 'selectedUser';}` and then we pass this to the 'Edit' view : `Ext.create('viewName', {viewModel:{data : selectedUser}});`

Now, in the simplest terms the 'user' model has a 'name' and 'language'. The edit form will have a text box for 'name' and a combobox for language. This combobox is bind to a store that contains all the languages with 'langId' and 'langName' as fields :

```
xtype: 'combobox',
displayField: 'langName',
valueField: 'langId',
bind: {
 store: '{allLangs}',
 value: '{allLangs.langId}',
 selection: '{selectedLang}'
}.
```

Also the 'Edit' form will have the textBox bind to the selectedUser's name :

`bind : {value : '{selectedUser.Name}'}`

Now, on `afterRender`  event,  I'm setting the value of the `langName` from the `selecteUser` as the selected value of the combobox :

```
var displayValue = viewModel.get('selectedUser').get('langName');
langCombo.setValue(displayValue);
```

OK, now how can you find out if the current record ('selectedUser') has the language changed ?
If I'm checking the `model.dirty` property is still `false` even if the value of the language is not the same as it was initially.
How do I have to bind the combobox so it will set the model's `dirty` property to `true` when the selected value was changed ?

Obviously if I'm editing the `name` the model will have the `dirty` property `true` .

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you think you can come up with a fiddle (https://fiddle.sencha.com)? Sometimes figuring out how to write a test case to help someone else is just too time consuming.

Comment: Hi Guilherme, I thought that there was some kind of pattern (best practices) for this kind of application workflow. On the other hand I will prepare a fiddle so we can look together at the issue I'm having . Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question .

Comment: I did not see any follow-up to this issue, and I have already created my own thread ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31707607/extjs-5-confusion-with-persisting-changes-to-view-model-form-record)) describing the same problem.  Any updates on this?

Comment: Hi incutonez, there is no follow up here as the ball was in my court (need to build a fiddle so I can describe the issue better) - now, looking at yours (fiddle) - it actually covers my issue as well (to some extent). So, i will keep on researching and also I will monitor both threads regarding this. If anything arises i will keep you posted.

Comment: And I will do the same, sir.  Thanks!

Comment: Dear 'icutonez' - in the end I think I found some sort of a 'solution' to the dirty problem.

Comment: Dear 'icutonez' - in the end I think I found some sort of a 'solution' to the dirty model problem. The idea here is to build an observable model. So, we will create a model that mixes in the observable: (code will follow) .

Comment: `code Ext.define('Apps.observableModel', {
 extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
 mixins: ['Ext.mixin.Observable'],

 listeners: {
  set: function (model, data) {
   // remove the event - call once
   this.events['set'].clearListeners();
  }
 },
 constructor: function () {
  this.mixins.observable.constructor.call(this);
  this.callParent(arguments);
 },
 
 set: function (fieldName, newValue, options) {
  var me = this;

  var modifiedFieldNames = me.callParent(arguments);
  me.fireEvent('set', me, modifiedFieldNames);
 }
});`   Sorry for the bad formatted code ...

Comment: @SevenIron, you should post this as an answer with a [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#home) to show it working... that would be awesome!  I was actually wondering this the other day... it would be nice if I could listen to model change events.

Comment: Hi @incutonez I will prepare the Sencha fiddle in the next couple of days. Thank you for your patience.